# Query a Partitioned MySQL DB With <= And >= In Where Clause

Tags: mysql, partitioning, partition, database-partitioning

I have a MySQL table (rangeTest) that has over 10 million rows of data that I need to query constantly in a web app and therefore needs to be very fast. Each row covers an Integer range as described by columns rangeStartInt and rangeEndInt. None of the integer ranges overlap from row to row and the run concurrently between rows. So for example a series of 5 rows would look as follows (they are the first two columns in the data below):

```
3758080000,3758084095,1835841,1835841,,0,0,,37.5112,126.9741,200
3758084096,3758085119,1835841,1835841,,0,0,,37.5112,126.9741,200
3758085120,3758086143,1841811,1835841,,0,0,,35.1547,126.9156,1
3758086144,3758088191,1835841,1835841,,0,0,,37.5112,126.9741,200
3758088192,3758088447,8314434,1643084,,0,0,,1.2000,104.0000,100
```

Each query returns a single row based on an integer number. For example an integer value 3758085130 would yield the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM rangeTest WHERE rangeStartInt <= 3758085130 AND rangeEndInt >= 3758085130
```

And this would return the following single row:

```
3758085120,3758086143,1841811,1835841,,0,0,,35.1547,126.9156,1
```

In un-partitioned form each query on the rangeTest table takes around 8 seconds. I have therefore added RANGE partitioning as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `rangeTest` (
 `rangeStartInt` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `rangeEndInt` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `a` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `b` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `c` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `d` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `e` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `f` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `g` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `h` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `i` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`rangeStartInt`,`rangeEndInt`,`a`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
 PARTITION BY RANGE  COLUMNS(rangeStartInt,rangeEndInt)
 (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (8000000,8000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (16000000,16000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (24000000,24000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (32000000,32000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (40000000,40000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (48000000,48000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (56000000,56000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (64000000,64000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (72000000,72000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (80000000,80000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (88000000,88000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (96000000,96000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (104000000,104000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (112000000,112000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (120000000,120000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN (128000000,128000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (136000000,136000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p17 VALUES LESS THAN (144000000,144000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN (152000000,152000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p19 VALUES LESS THAN (160000000,160000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN (168000000,168000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p21 VALUES LESS THAN (176000000,176000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN (184000000,184000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p23 VALUES LESS THAN (192000000,192000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN (200000000,200000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p25 VALUES LESS THAN (208000000,208000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p26 VALUES LESS THAN (216000000,216000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p27 VALUES LESS THAN (224000000,224000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p28 VALUES LESS THAN (232000000,232000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p29 VALUES LESS THAN (240000000,240000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (248000000,248000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p31 VALUES LESS THAN (256000000,256000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p32 VALUES LESS THAN (264000000,264000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p33 VALUES LESS THAN (272000000,272000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p34 VALUES LESS THAN (280000000,280000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p35 VALUES LESS THAN (288000000,288000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p36 VALUES LESS THAN (296000000,296000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p37 VALUES LESS THAN (304000000,304000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p38 VALUES LESS THAN (312000000,312000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p39 VALUES LESS THAN (320000000,320000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p40 VALUES LESS THAN (328000000,328000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p41 VALUES LESS THAN (336000000,336000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p42 VALUES LESS THAN (344000000,344000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p43 VALUES LESS THAN (352000000,352000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p44 VALUES LESS THAN (360000000,360000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p45 VALUES LESS THAN (368000000,368000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p46 VALUES LESS THAN (376000000,376000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p47 VALUES LESS THAN (384000000,384000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p48 VALUES LESS THAN (392000000,392000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p49 VALUES LESS THAN (400000000,400000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p50 VALUES LESS THAN (408000000,408000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p51 VALUES LESS THAN (416000000,416000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p52 VALUES LESS THAN (424000000,424000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p53 VALUES LESS THAN (432000000,432000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p54 VALUES LESS THAN (440000000,440000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p55 VALUES LESS THAN (448000000,448000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p56 VALUES LESS THAN (456000000,456000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p57 VALUES LESS THAN (464000000,464000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p58 VALUES LESS THAN (472000000,472000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p59 VALUES LESS THAN (480000000,480000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p60 VALUES LESS THAN (488000000,488000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p61 VALUES LESS THAN (496000000,496000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p62 VALUES LESS THAN (504000000,504000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p63 VALUES LESS THAN (512000000,512000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p64 VALUES LESS THAN (520000000,520000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p65 VALUES LESS THAN (528000000,528000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p66 VALUES LESS THAN (536000000,536000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p67 VALUES LESS THAN (544000000,544000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p68 VALUES LESS THAN (552000000,552000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p69 VALUES LESS THAN (560000000,560000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p70 VALUES LESS THAN (568000000,568000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p71 VALUES LESS THAN (576000000,576000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p72 VALUES LESS THAN (584000000,584000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p73 VALUES LESS THAN (592000000,592000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p74 VALUES LESS THAN (600000000,600000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p75 VALUES LESS THAN (608000000,608000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p76 VALUES LESS THAN (616000000,616000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p77 VALUES LESS THAN (624000000,624000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p78 VALUES LESS THAN (632000000,632000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p79 VALUES LESS THAN (640000000,640000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p80 VALUES LESS THAN (648000000,648000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p81 VALUES LESS THAN (656000000,656000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p82 VALUES LESS THAN (664000000,664000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p83 VALUES LESS THAN (672000000,672000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p84 VALUES LESS THAN (680000000,680000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p85 VALUES LESS THAN (688000000,688000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p86 VALUES LESS THAN (696000000,696000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p87 VALUES LESS THAN (704000000,704000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p88 VALUES LESS THAN (712000000,712000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p89 VALUES LESS THAN (720000000,720000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p90 VALUES LESS THAN (728000000,728000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p91 VALUES LESS THAN (736000000,736000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p92 VALUES LESS THAN (744000000,744000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p93 VALUES LESS THAN (752000000,752000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p94 VALUES LESS THAN (760000000,760000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p95 VALUES LESS THAN (768000000,768000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p96 VALUES LESS THAN (776000000,776000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p97 VALUES LESS THAN (784000000,784000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p98 VALUES LESS THAN (792000000,792000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p99 VALUES LESS THAN (800000000,800000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p100 VALUES LESS THAN (808000000,808000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p101 VALUES LESS THAN (816000000,816000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p102 VALUES LESS THAN (824000000,824000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p103 VALUES LESS THAN (832000000,832000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p104 VALUES LESS THAN (840000000,840000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p105 VALUES LESS THAN (848000000,848000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p106 VALUES LESS THAN (856000000,856000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p107 VALUES LESS THAN (864000000,864000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p108 VALUES LESS THAN (872000000,872000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p109 VALUES LESS THAN (880000000,880000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
```

...

```
  PARTITION p497 VALUES LESS THAN (3984000000,3984000000) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p498 VALUES LESS THAN (3992000000,3992000000) ENGINE = InnoDB
 )
```

To generate 500 partitions across the table. This works fine for any explicit SELECT searches by INT value as follows:

```
 explain partitions select * from rangeTest  where rangeStartInt  = 3758084096 AND rangeEndInt = 3758085119;
 +----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
 | id | select_type | table                        | partitions | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref         | rows | filtered | Extra |
 +----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | rangeTest                    | p469       | ref  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 16      | const,const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
 +----+-------------+------------------------------+------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------------+------+----------+-------+
```

With the relevant partition being used and the relevant row being returned in around 0.007s. However when I add the less than and more than operators into the mix the

```
 explain partitions select * from rangeTest  where rangeStartInt <=  3758084096 AND rangeEndInt >= 3758085119;
 +----+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
 | id | select_type | table                        | partitions                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | filtered | Extra       |
 +----+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | rangeTest             | p0,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10,p11,p12,p13,p14,p15,p16,p17,p18,p19,p20,p21,p22,p23,p24,p25,p26,p27,p28,p29,p30,p31,p32,p33,p34,p35,p36,p37,p38,p39,p40,p41,p42,p43,p44,p45,p46,p47,p48,p49,p50,p51,p52,p53,p54,p55,p56,p57,p58,p59,p60,p61,p62,p63,p64,p65,p66,p67,p68,p69,p70,p71,p72,p73,p74,p75,p76,p77,p78,p79,p80,p81,p82,p83,p84,p85,p86,p87,p88,p89,p90,p91,p92,p93,p94,p95,p96,p97,p98,p99,p100,p101,p102,p103,p104,p105,p106,p107,p108,p109,p110,p111,p112,p113,p114,p115,p116,p117,p118,p119,p120,p121,p122,p123,p124,p125,p126,p127,p128,p129,p130,p131,p132,p133,p134,p135,p136,p137,p138,p139,p140,p141,p142,p143,p144,p145,p146,p147,p148,p149,p150,p151,p152,p153,p154,p155,p156,p157,p158,p159,p160,p161,p162,p163,p164,p165,p166,p167,p168,p169,p170,p171,p172,p173,p174,p175,p176,p177,p178,p179,p180,p181,p182,p183,p184,p185,p186,p187,p188,p189,p190,p191,p192,p193,p194,p195,p196,p197,p198,p199,p200,p201,p202,p203,p204,p205,p206,p207,p208,p209,p210,p211,p212,p213,p214,p215,p216,p217,p218,p219,p220,p221,p222,p223,p224,p225,p226,p227,p228,p229,p230,p231,p232,p233,p234,p235,p236,p237,p238,p239,p240,p241,p242,p243,p244,p245,p246,p247,p248,p249,p250,p251,p252,p253,p254,p255,p256,p257,p258,p259,p260,p261,p262,p263,p264,p265,p266,p267,p268,p269,p270,p271,p272,p273,p274,p275,p276,p277,p278,p279,p280,p281,p282,p283,p284,p285,p286,p287,p288,p289,p290,p291,p292,p293,p294,p295,p296,p297,p298,p299,p300,p301,p302,p303,p304,p305,p306,p307,p308,p309,p310,p311,p312,p313,p314,p315,p316,p317,p318,p319,p320,p321,p322,p323,p324,p325,p326,p327,p328,p329,p330,p331,p332,p333,p334,p335,p336,p337,p338,p339,p340,p341,p342,p343,p344,p345,p346,p347,p348,p349,p350,p351,p352,p353,p354,p355,p356,p357,p358,p359,p360,p361,p362,p363,p364,p365,p366,p367,p368,p369,p370,p371,p372,p373,p374,p375,p376,p377,p378,p379,p380,p381,p382,p383,p384,p385,p386,p387,p388,p389,p390,p391,p392,p393,p394,p395,p396,p397,p398,p399,p400,p401,p402,p403,p404,p405,p406,p407,p408,p409,p410,p411,p412,p413,p414,p415,p416,p417,p418,p419,p420,p421,p422,p423,p424,p425,p426,p427,p428,p429,p430,p431,p432,p433,p434,p435,p436,p437,p438,p439,p440,p441,p442,p443,p444,p445,p446,p447,p448,p449,p450,p451,p452,p453,p454,p455,p456,p457,p458,p459,p460,p461,p462,p463,p464,p465,p466,p467,p468,p469 | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 8       | NULL | 5048679 |    33.33 | Using where |
 +----+-------------+------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

An I'm back to 8s for the query. So my question is how do I avoid this? I'm thinking I need an array in my application (Python) that calculates which partition I need to query and then only ever hits the DB with a request for that particular partition. This works and brings the query time right back down around 0.008s to but it seems pretty clunky as the table will be regularly updated via CSV imports and therefore the top end ranges might change, requiring changes to the Python array to accommodate this and avoid errors.

Am I on the right track in taking the Partition filtering out of MySQL and handling this in the Python code? Or is there something in MySQL that I'm missing for Greater than and Less than queries on partitioned tables?

Or is it possible re retrieve the partition ranges from MySQl in a query that I can then use in the Python code to calculate the relevant partition to use in the query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have non-overlapping integer ranges as the main "key" into the table.  MySQL does not have a spacial case for such.  In fact, none of the existing tools do a decent job of it.  Not even `PARTITION`.

Until Version 8.0, it is impractical to have 500 partitions in a table; 50 is a practical limit; various inefficiencies kick in after that.

No simple index on the table (partitioned or not) will do any better than (typically) scanning *half* the table.

But there is a solution.  See my [*blog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ipranges) on how to efficiently handle IP addresses.  You would need to adapt it to your type of numbers (and get rid of the INET_ATON-type code).

With my code, the typical query will touch only the rows needed; not half the table.